# internet connection over wifi using 2.4GHz instead 5GHz

Tags: wifi, share

For purpose of sharing internet connection to WiFi devices I've used either command line or very easy to setup and use program [Virtual Route Manager v1.0](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/). But it creates network using 5GHz band (channel 36). And now I have an Android device not working in this range.

I've tried all the [7 ways to share ethernet](http://www.wikihow.com/Share-Ethernet-As-Wi-Fi). There is no advice how to setup band and channel.

How can I make connection to work on 2.4GHz band?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thats easy..

Go to Your network connections

Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections

Select your wifi adapter

- Click on `Properties`
- Click on `Configure`
- Go to `Advanced section`
- Find preferred band and change it to 2.4 GHz
- Find `Channel width` and change it to 20 MHz ..

And Done..

:-) enjoy

Comment: Hope so this will be a good answer. But it is not working for me?

Answer (score 2):

That option (Preferred Band) is not present in Windows 10.
By connecting to a 2.4 router and starting your hotspot, you can broadcast a 2.4 signal. Then, reconnect to the 5 GHz signal and your hotspot will continue to work in the 2.4 band